# php artisan migrate all tables except few

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Is it possible to execute `php artisan migrate` in a way to migrate all the tables but leave only a few migration files under `database\migrations`?

The scenario is, our business requirement needs 2 DBs. So there are few migration files that explicitly mentions the 2nd DB. When I am creating another DB for PHPUnit, I don't need to run the migration files that are associated with the 2nd DB.

Comment: You mean that after you've run all migrations once, you would want to delete some of the already migrated files? If so, why?

Comment: migrate has --database option but I haven't tried how exactly works. I think your best option is to create your own migrate command.

Comment: we can provide --database option to migrate generic classes. But it doesn't works when the file specifies an explicit connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel exclude table from dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521584/laravel-exclude-table-from-dropping)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can place any migrations you don't want run automatically in a subfolder. For example:

```
/database
  /migrations
    /db2
      migration_3
    migration_1
    migration_2
```

Now when you run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Only the migrations in the `database/migrations` directory will be run (non-recursively, so the `db2` directory will not be traversed), meaning only `migration_1` and `migration_2` will be run.

To run the migrations in the `db2` directory separately you can use the `--path` option like so:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/db2
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea of migrating tables is progressive.

`php artisan migrate` will migrate all files within the `migrations` folder.

You cannot change it's order or ask certain migrations not to run.

You can create as many migration files as you want and use them to drop or add columns or tables.

If you need a bit hacking, you can create a sub folder inside `migrations` and move all unwanted migrations there, and run `php artisan migrate`. This will avoid the subfolder and all migrations in it.