# Laravel exclude table from dropping

Tags: laravel, migration

I have a large table which consists of millions of rows. I wanted to know how I could exclude this table from being dropped by `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out!

Comment: Does this Answer your Query - [php artisan migrate all tables except few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35440158/15405352)

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh` command first drops all tables and then migrate the migrations. I want to prevent some tables from being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask Laravel to create a new migration, the file it creates has two methods :

```
public function up()
```

which is what is executed when the migration is run, and

```
public function down()
```

which is what is executed when the migration is rolled back (either using the rollback command, or the refresh command).

By default, all that the down() method contains when the file is created is a step to drop the table :

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('table_name_here');
}
```

So in theory, if you wanted to, you could prevent your table from being dropped by removing that line from the migration.

The problem, though, is that using the "refresh" command means that it will rollback all migrations, and then run the migration again - at this point, if you've still got the up() function, the migration will fall over because it's trying to create a table that's already there (because it hasn't been removed).

So, I think your options are twofold :

1. Remove the table from the migrations completely (and remove any reference to it in the migrations table in the database) to prevent it being affected by migrations going on around it.
2. If it has to be handled through migrations (perhaps it has keys pointing to / from it to other tables) then I would export the content of the table as a raw SQL dump, save it in a file on your system, and then leave the migrations along - still have it being created / destroyed by the migration process, but use the "-- seed" option to put all the data back in it after a migration is run.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the migration file did not help and table is still dropping. And exporting and importing rows will take a while.

Comment: If you've removed the migration file for that specific table, unless the table is being dropped via another migration, I struggle to understand how the table would be dropped?

Comment: Laravel calls `dropAllTables()` in `migrate:fresh` and this function does not check what migrations exists or not.

Comment: Then consider using the migrate:refresh command rather than migrate:fresh?

Comment: @GilesBennett I like option 2 here. Do you have an example written for this? I think it'd be cool to add a one line function call to the Schema class like `dropIfExists` that dumps the data and then when running up it seeds the data from that dumped file.

Comment: Laravel docs have got information on how to create and implement seed files. I tend to just save the MySQL dump as a separate file and then incorporate it into the main DatabaseSeeder.php class using         

$config = 'database/files/config.sql';
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($config));

Not sure how that will come across in comment format.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments but I think is worth spelling out.

**use `php artisan:fresh` instead of refresh**

refresh calls `dropAllTables()` so avoid this if you want to keep anything

fresh runs all rollbacks and then all migrations

This has the side benefit of testing rollbacks (at least that they run).

You can then exclude the large table from migrations and manage it elsewhere.

It is also possible to put the large table as an early migration and only run migrations after this point

eg only refresh the last 5 migrations

`php artisan migrate:refresh --step=5`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

You may also want to run tests without dropping all tables.

By default Laravel runs `migrate:fresh` on every test run but this can be avoided by having a base TestCase like this

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabaseState;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use RefreshDatabase;



    /**
     * Override the standard method and use refresh instead of fresh
     *
     */
    protected function refreshTestDatabase()
    {
        if (! RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {
            $this->artisan('migrate:refresh', ['--seed' => true]);
            $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);
            RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
        }

        $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
    }

}
```

See the API docs for how RefreshDatabase works

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php#L70