# Is there a reason why the spatie package laravel-tags has no down() function in migration

Tags: laravel

I got the package laravel-tags from my favourite package provider spatie into the project to test it. After the first tests I wanted to empty the tables with `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` to run further tests. But I get the exception:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "tags" already exists (SQL: create table "tags" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "name" text not null, "slug" text not null, "type" varchar, "order_column" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime))`

A look into the migration file showed me that there is no down() function of the migration of Spatie. So the data remains persistent and I can't start a rollback or reset. I don't like this at all. I added a down function munell, but even there I get the above exception. Hence my two questions:

1. Is there a reason not to deliver a down() function?
2. What do I have to do to empty the new table?

Thanks in advance, Max

Comment: This would probably be better as a question/issue on their package, not Stackoverflow, as we're not the maintainers for this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags. You're correct, you can publish and modify the migration, including adding the missing `down()` function, but I don't know why it's missing; seems... odd.

Comment: Sidenote, looks like this has actually already been asked: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags/issues/420 (and by extension, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags/issues/121)

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. This is news to me that there is a trend to omit the down() function. To be honest, I don't see why it should be done. Because you need it when you are building and testing.

Comment: @TimLewis BTW: I'll ask around. If I get an answer I will post it here and if you want I will ping you.

Comment: Agreed 100%; indeed the question has been asked, but the "answers" in them leave a lot to be desired  Writing a migration that is not reversible in some form goes against everything I know about migrations... And thanks! I'm curious too, as I've just started looking into the world of package development in Laravel.

Comment: I am also very interessted in what kind of answer you get :-). And I complety agree with @TimLewis and you. I will bookmark the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your second question you can use `php artisan db:wipe`. That will drop all tables successfully.

To your first question:

> Is there a reason not to deliver a down() function?

It is not standard to omit the down function in the migration. But why Spatie did it in this case I can only speculate. So it is hard to answer but good that you ask the question. Just add the `down()` function manually. After you have deleted the DB once, it should also work with the future rollbacks and resets.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's common practice to only use `migrate:fresh` which doesn't run rollbacks and just drops all tables.

If you're doing this any `down()` functions go unused, untested and are easily neglected.

Testing by default performs a `migrate:fresh` so you have extra work to do if you want to run tests and rely on rollbacks.

Effectively Laravel encourages regular nuking of the database - this is simplicity is helpful in some use cases.

If nuking the database works for you - run `migrate:fresh`

If you need to preserve some tables - provide your own `down()` method and see [Laravel exclude table from dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521584/laravel-exclude-table-from-dropping/74786907#74786907)